# Postgres 11. Authentication using pg_bouncer + kerberos

Tags: postgresql, kerberos, pgbouncer

We've got Postgres 11 server and Kerberos authentication.
My teammates asked to find out if we can also use pg_bouncer with Kerberos.
Does anyone use with combination (Kerberos + pg_bouncer).
Or where can I find settings?

Comment: You can find settings in the docs (https://www.pgbouncer.org/config.html).  It doesn't included any for kerberos, so I would say it is not implemented.  That would be an odd thing to leave undocumented.

Comment: Yeahh...found this discussion https://github.com/pgbouncer/pgbouncer/issues/318 
It is not said that it is impossible) . Even somebody made something, but not finished)